# Why it is necessary to prove that $B$ is a linear transformation in this proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

> **Theorem :-** Let $A : X → Y$ be a linear transformation. Then $A$ is
>   invertible if and only if for any right side $\mathbf b ∈ Y$ the equation
>   $$A \mathbf x =\mathbf b$$
>   has a unique solution $\mathbf x ∈ X$.
>
> **Proof :-**
>
> **Part 1**
>
> Suppose $A$ is invertible. Then $\mathbf x = A^{−1}\mathbf b$ solves the equation $A\mathbf x = \mathbf b$. To show that the solution is unique, suppose that for some other vector $\mathbf x_1 ∈ X$, $A\mathbf x_1 =\mathbf b$. Multiplying this identity by $A^{−1}$ from the left we get
>   $$A^{−1} A\mathbf x_1 = A^{−1} \mathbf b$$,
>   and therefore $\mathbf x_1 = A^{−1}\mathbf b =\mathbf x$.
>
> **Part 2**
>
> Suppose $$A \mathbf x = \mathbf y$$ has a unique solution $\mathbf x$ for all $\mathbf y \in Y$. Let this unique solution be $B(\mathbf y)$.
>
> We define a transformation $B : Y \to X$, since $B(\mathbf y)$ is defined for all $\mathbf y \in Y$. Now we need to prove that $B$ is a linear transformation.
>
> Let $\mathbf x_1 := B(\mathbf y_1)$ and $\mathbf x_2 := B(\mathbf y_2)$, so $A \mathbf x_1 = \mathbf y_1$ and $A \mathbf x_2 = \mathbf y_2$. Then
>
> $$A(\alpha \mathbf x_1 + \beta \mathbf x_2) = \alpha A (\mathbf x_1) + \beta A (\mathbf x_2) = \alpha \mathbf y_1 + \beta \mathbf y_2$$
>
> Therefore,
>
> $$B(\alpha \mathbf y_1 + \beta \mathbf y_2) = \alpha B (\mathbf y_1) + \beta B (\mathbf y_2).$$
>
> **Part 3**
>
> And finally, let us show that $B$ is indeed the inverse of $A$. Take $x ∈ X$ and let $\mathbf y = A\mathbf x$, so by the definition of $B$ we have $\mathbf x = B\mathbf y$. Then for all $\mathbf x ∈ X$, $$BA\mathbf x = B\mathbf y = \mathbf x$$,
>   so $BA = I$. Similarly, for arbitrary $\mathbf y ∈ Y$ let $\mathbf x = B\mathbf y$, so $\mathbf y = A\mathbf x$. Then for all $\mathbf y ∈ Y$
>   $$AB\mathbf y = A\mathbf x =\mathbf y$$
>   so $AB = I$.

I divided the proof in three parts. In **part 1**, we proved that if $A^{-1}$ exists then $A \mathbf x = \mathbf b$ has unique solution, in **part 2** we proved that $B$ is a linear map and in **part 3** we proved that $AB = BA =I$.

I am failing to understand why **part 3** is dependent on **part 2**. Why we need $B$ to be a linear transformation to prove that it is the inverse of $A$?

Comment: For Part 3, we need the existence of $B$, which is also proved in Part 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We *don't* need $B$ to be linear in order to prove that it is the inverse of $A$. When we have a function $f\colon M\longrightarrow N$ such that, for each $n\in N$, there is one and only one $m\in M$ such that $f(m)=n$, if we define $g\colon N\longrightarrow M$ by: if $n=f(m)$, then $g(n)=m$, then $g$ is *always* the inverse of $f$.

Comment: Well, seems fine only if you're working in category of sets!

Comment: @Dontknowanything Vector spaces *are* sets and linear maps *are* functions.

Comment: Of course! But i think usually when we work in other categories usually people define inverse by the morphism of that category!

Comment: @Dontknowanything Of course. Nevertheless, if our category is a category of sets with an extra structure, and if our morphims are maps, the inverse of a morphism $f$, if it exists, is still the inverse of the map $f$.

Comment: Agree completely! I was just mentioning because  it seems the OP is confused due to definition of inverse in category of Vector spaces!

Comment: @Dontknowanything Now I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wolfram|MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleLinearMap.html), an invertible linear transformation $T$ is defined as,

> A linear transformation $T\colon X\to Y$ is invertible iff there exists a **linear transformation** $S\colon Y\to X$ such that $ST=\textrm{id}_X$ and $TS=\textrm{id}_Y$. In that case, we call $T$ an invertible linear map with inverse $S$.

This is the reason the proof shows that the inverse transformation is also a linear map.

Comment: It is not difficult to show that the (set theoretic) inverse of a linear map must also be linear.

Comment: @DavidHill, I never said it wasn't difficult. I just answered the query in OP's post. Note that the posted problem says that $A\colon X\to Y$ is a linear transformation and thus the part of the proof showing that the inverse transformation $B\colon Y\to X$ is linear is required because an invertible linear map is _defined_ that way.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The other answer only addresses the existence of a set-theoretic inverse, but invertibility of a linear map depends on the linearity of the set-theoretic inverse.